# How to add custom neo4j browser guide as Built in Guide?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

It is possible to create custom neo4j browser guide and run it.
Ex: `:play http://guides.neo4j.com/graphgist/restaurant_recommendation.html`.
Also neo4j has default browser guides like `:play cypher`.

I want to make my neo4j guide as built in guide like `:play mycustomguide`
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's only possible for guides that currently reside on guides.neo4j.com

You'd have to patch the browser code for that. github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser

But you can configure in neo4j.conf a start command that allows you to play your guide automatically at the beginning, see:

https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-create-neo4j-browser-guide/

Comment: I configured neo4j.conf to play my guide automatically and it works.
Also built in guides located in `neo4j-browser/src/browser/modules/Guides/html`